# USB audio only outputs white noise

Tags: audio, usb, openbsd

I am running OpenBSD/i386 5.1 on a 5 year old laptop. The speakers and headphone port work, but the headphone port is a little loose so I am trying to install an external USB sound card (Fiio E17 USB DAC). No problems using it on Windows.

The device is detected and I created a node for it in `/dev` with `sh /dev/MAKEDEV audio1`, then linked the rest of the devices to point to the new sound card. So far so good, I am able to run `cat /dev/urandom > /dev/audio` and I hear white noise. However, I am not able to run any other audio through it.

My `tail /var/log/messages` after plugging the device in:

```
Aug 30 10:03:55 s96j /bsd: uhidev0 at uhub1
Aug 30 10:03:55 s96j /bsd:  port 1 configuration 1 interface 0 "FiiO FiiO USB DAC-E17" rev 1.10/0.01 addr 2
Aug 30 10:03:55 s96j /bsd: uhidev0: iclass 3/0
Aug 30 10:03:55 s96j /bsd: uhid0 at uhidev0: input=18, output=27, feature=0
Aug 30 10:03:55 s96j /bsd: uaudio0 at uhub1
Aug 30 10:03:55 s96j /bsd:  port 1 configuration 1 interface 1 "FiiO FiiO USB DAC-E17" rev 1.10/0.01 addr 2
Aug 30 10:03:56 s96j /bsd: uaudio0: ignored setting with type 8193 format
Aug 30 10:03:56 s96j /bsd: uaudio0: audio rev 1.00, 2 mixer controls
Aug 30 10:03:56 s96j /bsd: audio1 at uaudio0
```

My list of relevant devices from `/dev`:

```
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel         6 Aug 30 09:44 audio -> audio1
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel   42, 128 Aug 30 10:07 audio0
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel   42, 129 Aug 30 10:15 audio1
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel   42, 130 Aug 30 06:40 audio2
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel         9 Aug 30 09:44 audioctl -> audioctl1
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel   42, 192 Aug 30 06:40 audioctl0
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel   42, 193 Aug 30 09:44 audioctl1
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel   42, 194 Aug 30 06:40 audioctl2
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel         6 Aug 30 09:45 mixer -> mixer1
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel   42,  16 Aug 30 06:40 mixer0
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel   42,  17 Aug 30 09:44 mixer1
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel   42,  18 Aug 30 06:40 mixer2
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel         6 Aug 30 09:45 sound -> sound1
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel   42,   0 Aug 30 06:40 sound0
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel   42,   1 Aug 30 09:44 sound1
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel   42,   2 Aug 30 06:40 sound2
```

A simple test from the [FAQ](http://www.openbsd.org/faq/faq13.html#audioprob) to determine if data is passing over the device:

```
# cat > /dev/audio < /dev/zero &
[1] 21098
# audioctl play.{seek,samples,errors}
play.seek=61712
play.samples=1146080
play.errors=0
# audioctl play.{seek,samples,errors}
play.seek=52896
play.samples=1542800
play.errors=0
# audioctl play.{seek,samples,errors}
play.seek=61712
play.samples=1957152
play.errors=0
```

My `audioctl -a`:

```
name=USB audio
version=
config=uaudio
encodings=slinear_le:16:2:1,slinear_le:24:3:1
properties=independent
full_duplex=0
fullduplex=0
blocksize=8816
hiwat=7
lowat=1
output_muted=0
monitor_gain=0
mode=
play.rate=44100
play.sample_rate=44100
play.channels=2
play.precision=16
play.bps=2
play.msb=1
play.encoding=slinear_le
play.gain=127
play.balance=32
play.port=0x0
play.avail_ports=0x0
play.seek=8816
play.samples=131988
play.eof=0
play.pause=0
play.error=1
play.waiting=0
play.open=0
play.active=0
play.buffer_size=65536
play.block_size=8816
play.errors=2267
record.rate=44100
record.sample_rate=44100
record.channels=2
record.precision=16
record.bps=2
record.msb=1
record.encoding=slinear_le
record.gain=127
record.balance=32
record.port=0x0
record.avail_ports=0x0
record.seek=0
record.samples=0
record.eof=0
record.pause=0
record.error=0
record.waiting=0
record.open=0
record.active=0
record.buffer_size=65536
record.block_size=8816
record.errors=0
```

And lastly, my `mixerctl -a`:

```
outputs.aux.mute=off
outputs.aux=255,255
```

Again I am able to `cat /dev/urandom > /dev/audio` and get white noise, but nothing else I've tried lets me output other sounds or music. I also tried `cat sample.au > /dev/audio` but that was silent as well.

Any suggestions or help would be greatly appreciated! Worst case, hopefully someone can use the steps I outlined here to troubleshoot their own sound devices.

Comment: what is the output of `mixerctl -v |grep output` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On OpenBSD audio playback/recording is handled by the [sndiod(1)](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=sndiod&manpath=OpenBSD%20Current&sektion=1&format=html) daemon by default. The device names are documented under [sndio(7)](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=sndio&manpath=OpenBSD%20Current&sektion=7&format=html) as follows:

```
 type      The type of the audio device or MIDI port.  Possible values
           are:

              rsnd      Raw audio(4) device.
              rmidi     Raw midi(4) port.
              snd       Audio device exposed by sndiod(1).
              midithru  MIDI thru box created with sndiod(1).
              midi      MIDI port exposed by sndiod(1).
              default   Default audio device or MIDI port (see below).
```

The output of `dmesg` indicates that your USB is on `audio1`, so add the following to `/etc/rc.conf.local` in order to specify two raw [audio(4)](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=audio&manpath=OpenBSD%20Current&sektion=4&format=html) devices using the second as the default:

```
sndiod_flags="-f rsnd/1 -f rsnd/0"
```

Then run `/etc/rc.d/sndiod restart`. The `-f` flag also works with `aucat` for playback or recording of audio:

```
aucat -f rsnd/1 -i my.wav # second "raw" audio device 
aucat -f snd/1 -i my.wav  # second sndiod device
```

Comment: Thank you! Your answer and the `sndiod(1)` man page put me on the right track and the device is working great. I appreciate your help.