# Connect external DAC / sound card in OpenBSD

Tags: audio, openbsd, usb-audio

I am trying to connect a Focusrite Scarlett 2i4 USB DAC to my OpenBSD system to use as an external sound card. From what I have figured out so far, it seems that I need to tell some program or other that the "audio1 device" is the DAC. I seems that sndio, sndiod, audio, audioctl, and mixerctl may be involved here, but the respective man pages are as unhelpful as always. I found a [blog post](http://blog.boreas.ro/2007/12/openbsd-and-usb-audio-cards.html) that points out that I need to:

> Configure /dev/audio, /dev/audioctl, /dev/mixer to point to /dev/audio1 or whatever dmesg reports as your new audio card...

Of course, silly me, I need to configure it. Unfortunately my big red CONFIGURE button seems to be broken. Any idea how to do this manually?

[This here forum post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/46742/usb-audio-only-outputs-white-noise) also alludes to pointing the "device" to the actual device, saying:

> The device is detected and I created a node for it in /dev with sh /dev/MAKEDEV audio1, then linked the rest of the devices to point to the new sound card.

I assume this is the same feat of magic which I seek to learn here. I do have a file /dev/audio1, however it does not show up in dmesg. Here is the output of $ dmesg | grep audio

```
audio0 at azalia1
uaudio0 at uhub0 port 4 configuration 1 interface 0 "Focusrite Scarlett 2i4 USB" rev 2.00/1.25 addr 3
uaudio0: audio descriptors make no sense, error=4
uaudio1 at uhub0 port 4 configuration 1 interface 3 "Focusrite Scarlett 2i4 USB" rev 2.00/1.25 addr 3
uaudio1: audio descriptors make no sense, error=4
uaudio0 detached
uaudio1 detached
uaudio0 at uhub0 port 4 configuration 1 interface 0 "Focusrite Scarlett 2i4 USB" rev 2.00/1.25 addr 3
uaudio0: audio descriptors make no sense, error=4
uaudio1 at uhub0 port 4 configuration 1 interface 3 "Focusrite Scarlett 2i4 USB" rev 2.00/1.25 addr 3
uaudio1: audio descriptors make no sense, error=4
```

and of dmesg | grep Focusrite

```
uaudio0 at uhub0 port 4 configuration 1 interface 0 "Focusrite Scarlett 2i4 USB" rev 2.00/1.25 addr 3
uaudio1 at uhub0 port 4 configuration 1 interface 3 "Focusrite Scarlett 2i4 USB" rev 2.00/1.25 addr 3
umidi0 at uhub0 port 4 configuration 1 interface 4 "Focusrite Scarlett 2i4 USB" rev 2.00/1.25 addr 3
ugen0 at uhub0 port 4 configuration 1 "Focusrite Scarlett 2i4 USB" rev 2.00/1.25 addr 3
uaudio0 at uhub0 port 4 configuration 1 interface 0 "Focusrite Scarlett 2i4 USB" rev 2.00/1.25 addr 3
uaudio1 at uhub0 port 4 configuration 1 interface 3 "Focusrite Scarlett 2i4 USB" rev 2.00/1.25 addr 3
umidi0 at uhub0 port 4 configuration 1 interface 4 "Focusrite Scarlett 2i4 USB" rev 2.00/1.25 addr 3
ugen0 at uhub0 port 4 configuration 1 "Focusrite Scarlett 2i4 USB" rev 2.00/1.25 addr 3
```

EDIT: What dmesg should be saying at some point, but isn't, is something along the lines of

```
audio1 at uaudio0
```

So, how do I point anything at audio1, what exactly should I point there, and then what? My /etc/rc.conf.local contains

```
sndiod_flags=-f rsnd/1
```

which should mean that the second audio device is the default, right? But since only one (internal soundcard of the computer = audio0 at azalia1 = rsnd/0 (?)) is mounted or whatever that is called, that one is used.

EDIT: I found something in the [OpenBSD FAQs](http://www.openbsd.org/faq/faq13.html#midi) about Midi devices that may be related. Says here:

> The output of the keyboard can be connected to the input of the synthesizer, as follows:

```
$ cat -u < /dev/rmidi0 > /dev/rmidi1
```

That would simply replace the contents of rmidi1 with those of rmidi0, no? Is this the mysterious "pointing" that I seem to be looking for? And if so, which file do I want to cat into which? Preferably without mucking up the rest of the audio configuration (i.e. audio0 at azalia1).

Thanks for any helpful comments,

Os

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue, running openbsd 6.6 with a focusrite scarlite 2i2. After reading this post and searching some more I can across this link (https://www.mail-archive.com/misc@openbsd.org/msg171434.html). I set my flags in /etc/rc.conf.local to be:

```
sndiod_flags=-f rsnd/0 -F rsnd/1
```

And did a full reboot to make sure the changes took place and then everything was working.